# Can't convince initramfs of my new swap partition

Tags: debian, swap, initramfs

(Running Debian 10.2 XFCE)

Due to some partition resizing needs, I had to delete my original swap partition and add a new one. I changed the entry in **/etc/fstab** - swap is recognized and working. I changed the entry in **/etc/default/grub** - ran **update-grub** with no errors.

Now, when running the final step - **update-initramfs -u** - it complains about the old swap UUID not existing. I found a question that was the exact problem I'm having (http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?t=133578), but the fix doesn't work. I'm still getting the *Begin: Running /scripts/local-block ... done.* message about 15 times, then the boot finally finished.

Once I'm able to login, I find no errors with either **dmesg** or **journalctl**. I personally don't care about being able to suspend, so if there's a way to disable this I'm all for it. I did try that (removed the RESUME= entry from **/etc/default/grub**), but that didn't help either.

**/etc/fstab**

```
UUID=40728a0b-10e9-4599-9bb1-1db16e95db8c /boot     ext2    defaults    0 0
UUID=e0fef258-68d0-41b1-9326-dbdc37083000 /         btrfs   subvol=@,defaults,noatime,space_cache,autodefrag    0 1
UUID=e0fef258-68d0-41b1-9326-dbdc37083000 /home     btrfs   subvol=@home,defaults,noatime,space_cache,autodefrag    0 2
UUID=1aea03e4-a509-41c7-8e3e-ad547b34ddd9 swap      swap    defaults,noatime0 2
```

**blkid**

```
/dev/vda1: LABEL="Boot" UUID="40728a0b-10e9-4599-9bb1-1db16e95db8c" TYPE="ext2" PARTUUID="90f85121-01"
/dev/vda2: UUID="e0fef258-68d0-41b1-9326-dbdc37083000" UUID_SUB="84f77425-e0fe-4537-8b2c-b5838f8d70df" TYPE="btrfs" PARTUUID="90f85121-02"
/dev/vda3: UUID="1aea03e4-a509-41c7-8e3e-ad547b34ddd9" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="90f85121-03"
```

**/etc/default/grub**

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT=5
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR='Debian'
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="resume=UUID=1aea03e4-a509-41c7-8e3e-ad547b34ddd9"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why this was necessary, but the problem was fixed after I ran:

```
sudo grub-install /dev/vda
sudo reboot
```

Hopefully this will help someone else in the future.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check `/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume`: if it contains a reference to the old swap UUID, you might want to change/remove it from there too, just in case.

Any configuration files in that directory are included in initramfs, so after making any changes, you should run `update-initramfs -u`.

Comment: That file didn't exist, so I created it after I made the swap change. Didn't make any difference until I ran grub-install.